# Boost Python Magic Number

Tags: python, boost, magic-numbers

I am trying to wrap some C++ functions for use in python. For example here is the function from the boost Python tutorial.

```
//  Copyright Joel de Guzman 2002-2004. Distributed under the Boost
//  Software License, Version 1.0. (See accompanying file LICENSE_1_0.txt
//  or copy at http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)
//  Hello World Example from the tutorial
//  [Joel de Guzman 10/9/2002]

#include <boost/python/module.hpp>
#include <boost/python/def.hpp>

char const* greet()
{
   return "hello, world";
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello_ext)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    def("greet", greet);
}
```

When I compile this into a .pyc file and try to import it into python I receive the error:

> ImportError: Bad magic number in C:\hello_ext.pyc

I have checked the magic number using a method from another forum and it does seem to be wrong. I googled around and I haven't been able to find any useful information regarding this error message. I suspect this is a bad setting in my visual studio project file, or maybe something with the way I compiled boost?

I am using visual studio 2010 service pack 1, python 2.7.3 and boost 1.53

I compiled boost with the following options.

```
b2 install toolset=msvc-10.0 variant=debug,release threading=multi link=shared runtime-link=shared --prefix="C:\boost"
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem. I feel just a little stupid now :)

Comment: If you want to add this as an answer I will mark it correct.

Answer (score 1):

When you compile boost python, you should have got a shared library as a result (e.g. *.so on my machine), not the .pyc files..

This is a page on how to build boost python extension:
http://wiki.python.org/moin/boost.python/BuildingExtensions